# Gradle multi-project dependencies with snapshots

Tags: gradle, multi-project

I have a multiple project build with flat paths, e.g.:

```
settings.gradle:
includeFlat 'projA','projB','projC'
```

There are about 20 different sub-projects with all sorts of different interdependencies. I'd like gradle to handle the dependencies but I don't want to tie the entire project together as a monolith, I want to keep these as individual uploads which go into our artifact repository (Nexus) with their individual sub-project versioning.  Each sub-project has its group specified in the `gradle.properties` file.

The problem is, if I call out the dependencies via the compile dependency, i.e.:

```
projA-build.gradle:
compile project(":projB")
```

Then everything compiles and the artifacts are uploaded just fine but at runtime I get an error such as:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
Could not find master:restclient:4.0-SNAPSHOT.
```

The upload is in the `master` `build.gradle` file.  The relevant portion of the build script:

```
subprojects {
  afterEvaluate { Project proj ->
      def is_snap = false
      def reltype = "releases"
      def artifact_name = sprintf("%s-%s.jar" 
                               ,project['name']
                                 ,project['version'])
      def nexus_release_path = sprintf("%s/nexus/content/repositories/releases/%s/%s/%s/%s"
                               ,project['nexus_url']
                               ,project['groupId'].replaceAll("\\.","/")
                               ,project['name']
                               ,project['version']
                               ,artifact_name
                               )

      if(project.version.contains("SNAPSHOT")){
          reltype = "snapshots"
          is_snap = true
      }

      uploadArchives {
        // only try the upload if it's not already there
        onlyIf {
          try {
            def artifact_exists = new URL(nexus_release_path).bytes
            // if we get here then the artifact existed and we only want to
            // build if this is a snapshot version
            is_snap || false
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // this means we couldn't find the artifact in nexus
            if(!is_snap){
              println "NOTE ==> Don't forget to create new git tag for $artifact_name!"
            } 
            true
          }
        }

        repositories {
          mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "${project.nexus_url}/nexus/content/repositories/$reltype") {
              authentication(userName: project.nexus_user, password: project.nexus_password)
            }
            pom.version = "${project['version']}"
            pom.artifactId = "${project.name}"
            pom.groupId = "${groupId}"
          }
        }
      }
...
}
```

Though it's uploaded to Nexus correctly somehow the dependency is built in with that "master" in the artifact coordinates.

Am I going about this the wrong way or have the wrong expectations?

Comment: Did you specify the correct `group` in Gradle? How do you upload to Nexus? Could you add the relevant parts of your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: I updated the question.  I included what I'm using to upload artifacts, again note that the upload works fine - it does not upload to `master:subjproj` rather to the appropriate group/name for that subproject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html) instances provide default properties for Maven coordinates:

> - `Object group`
>
>   The group of this project. Gradle always uses the `toString()` value of the group. The group defaults to the path with dots as separators.
> - `String name` (read-only)
>
>   The name of this project. The project's name is not necessarily unique within a project hierarchy. You should use the `Project.getPath()` method for a unique identifier for the project.
> - `Object version`
>
>   The version of this project. Gradle always uses the `toString()` value of the version. The version defaults to `unspecified`.

You can use these properties in your `build.gradle` file to specify or use the respective values, e.g.:

```
group = 'my.company.group'
```

Please note that the `name` property is read-only inside your `build.gradle` file, but you can set the name of your project inside the `settings.gradle` file before the `Project` instance will be created.

Gradle uses these values to transform project dependencies into module dependencies, which is required when uploading to a repository. When uploading your artifacts, you manually set the Maven coordinates for your project (by setting `pom.version`, `pom.artifactId` and `pom.groupId`). For both `version` and `artifactId` you refer to the default properties provided by Gradle. However, for `groupId` you use your own custom property called `groupId`. I can't find your defintion of `groupId`, but I'm sure you specify it somewhere, leaving the default property `group` at its default value (the property `path` separated with dots). As a solution I would recommend you to set the default property `group` and somewhere and, if needed, use it inside your code:

```
pom.version = project.version
pom.artifactId = project.name
pom.groupId = project.group
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I do set `groupId` in the `gradle.properties` file and I set `pom.groupId` to my custom `groupId` but I don't explicitly set `project.group`.  I'll give that a try and let you know.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not 100% sure that this answer alone worked for me but I did this in addition to setting up dependencies in the `master/build.gradle` file (e.g., `project(":projA"){ dependencies.compile project(":projB") }`. In the subproject build files I still have the literal version dependency (e.g., `compile org.group:projA:1.1`) but the master build file causes the dependency to be ran and the artifact uploaded.  Thanks for your suggestion.